# How to use cljsjs.phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, clojurescript

I am trying to use the cljsjs package phoenix.
I started out with a simple figwheel example:

lein new figwheel systems.casemgr.utils.hello-world -- --om

I added [cljsjs/phoenix "1.3.0-0"] to my project file.
I added it as a require to my sample core:

```
 [cljsjs.phoenix]
```

However, I can't seem to get the naming right for a Socket.
I am trying:

```
(def socket (js/phoenix.Socket.))
```

The example shows:

```
(js/GlobalName.someFunction)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
core.cljs?rel=1508705017340:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: phoenix is not defined
    at core.cljs?rel=1508705017340:16
```

I am trying to create a socket to connect to a running phoenix server.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the spelling of the Phoenix global var - it should be [`js/Phoenix`, not `js/phoenix`](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/phoenix/resources/cljsjs/common/phoenix.ext.js#L1):

```
(def socket (js/Phoenix.Socket.))
```

Comment: This worked: `(def socket (js/Phoenix.Socket. "ws://localhost:4000/socket"  (clj->js {"params:" {"userToken:" "123"}})))`